# How get save apk name in server on android?

Tags: android

I upload 1.0.1.apk in my server.

I want compare my device installed apk to 1.0.1 apk in my server .

recently I get  installed apk in my device app version

```
     PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo pInfo1= null;
    try {
        pInfo1=manager.getPackageInfo("package name", 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String oldVersion = pInfo1.versionName;
    Log.d(TAG, "Current version = " + oldVersion);
```

but I don't know how get apk version in my server.

so, I wrote app name is version information. 
1.0.1

I want compare my versionname  to apk name in server.

How get I save apk name in server on android ?

thanks.

Comment: Your app should ask your server the latest version.

Comment: Or your app should tell the server its version.

Comment: You have asked this before. Only five hours before. You are not referring to that. Why you ask again?

Answer (score 0):

I would give the apk file a name that contains the version. i.e. MyApp_v1.0.1.apk. Then you can parse the name of file and get the version out of it.

Answer (score 0):

**get application version in gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile, new BooleanSupplier() {
               @Override
               boolean getAsBoolean() {
                   return true
               }
           }, null)
            def versionCode = manifestParser.getVersionName()

.......
.......
}
}
```